# Not able to see column headers in Datasets of Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, dataverse

I have imported Dataverse tables into AZ Data lake using Azure synapse link in Powerapps.
I got the tables in CSV  format in AZ data lake container. Now using azure data factory, I Want to drill down this data with some filters and sink it into new csv file. While achieving this, I created dataset for each csv file and both csv file and dataset doesn't show up the column headers. I did select "First row as header" option but still no luck. Please help me if anyone has gone through the same and fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ingest dataverse into data lake using the synapse link, the data will stored in a CDM format. In CDM, the schema is not stored in the CSVs as header, it is stored in the model.json file.

The proper way to read CDM in data factory is by using mapping data flows with source set as Common Data Model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/export-to-data-lake-data-adf

this will take care of schema handling for you, and knows how to read the correct files for entities in the CDM structure.

Comment: Thank you soo much. This helped me at right time. :)